# Strange memory access error on actions

Tags: windows

There is one error happening in one of my local machines *(3 machines)*, which remains unsolved for me.

I'm running `Microsoft Windows XP SP3`, all latest updates and the error happens on attempts to do something with `.lst` or `.ver` files.

On any attempt to access them and `Invalid memory access` error is triggered *(code 998)*. Also, if you rename any existant file into a `.lst` or `.ver` file, it becomes inaccessible.

Now, I could simply restore the working state of my machine *(I've got backups)*, but this error seems interesting to me and **I really want to solve it.**

---

P.S *There are people with the same error in the internet, but looks like it still remains unsolved.*

Another P.S *My first thoughts were about some sophisticated rootkit, which for some reasons was injecting it's code into the file reading calls, but my rootkit checks were unsuccessful.*

Comment: Do you have .lst and .ver under Hkey_classes_root? I noticed they were there on win 7 with no sub keys but nonexistent on fresh xp sp3 install... if so is there anything set to launch with those extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, this was a trojan, which was actually hooking my `NtFileXXX` calls.

*They were redirected to `C:\Windows\lsacc.sys`.*

Comment: Sounds evil, any info on what you did to clear the infection?